# Displaying values from related field - if empty shows current post type's link and title

Tags: post-meta, php

I'm working with custom post types. In the post type awards I have a relationship field that links each award to a post from the post type project.

I'm using the following code to return the values from this field - it should not return anything if $work_value is empty:

```
<?php 
$work_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'work', false );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $work_value ) ) {
    foreach ( $work_value as $work ) { 
        //get id for related post and put in ID
        $id = $work[ 'ID' ];
        //show the related post name as link
        echo 'for <a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a> ';
    } //end of foreach
} //endif ! empty ( $work_value )
?>
```

However, if the field is empty (and I checked, it really is empty) it outputs the permalink and title of the current post (from post type awards). How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What is `var_dump($work_value);` right before the `if` conditional?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) } //

if it has a value it's: array(1) { [0]=> array(23) etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_post_meta()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1769) should only `return false` under a couple of circumstances:

> ```
> 269   function get_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key = '', $single = false) {
> 270           if ( !$meta_type )
> 271                   return false;
> 272   
> 273           if ( !$object_id = absint($object_id) )
> 274                   return false;
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L269

I don't see how `$meta_type` could be wrong since it is hard-coded into `get_post_meta()`:

> ```
> 1769  function get_post_meta($post_id, $key = '', $single = false) {
> 1770          return get_metadata('post', $post_id, $key, $single);
> 1771  }
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1769

That leaves `$object_id`. Something could be passing an bad object ID-- something like this...

```
$object_id = 'abc';
// or this
// $object_id = -123;
var_dump(!$object_id = absint($object_id));
```

... will evaluate `true` causing `get_post_meta` to return `false`.

Another possibility is that a filter is returning a problematic value here:

> ```
> 276           $check = apply_filters( "get_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single );
> 277           if ( null !== $check ) {
> 278                   if ( $single && is_array( $check ) )
> 279                           return $check[0];
> 280                   else
> 281                           return $check;
> 282           }
> ```

If some filter sets `$check` to an array with `false` as the only element, then `null !== $check` is `true` and that array gets returned. For example:

```
add_filter(
  'get_post_metadata',
  function($meta) {
    return array(false);
  }
);
$t = get_post_meta(1,'_edit_lock_dood',false);
var_dump($t,empty($t));
```

Note: simply `return`ing `false` from that filter won't do it. It must be an array with `false` as the single element, which gets to the technical reason your code doesn't work.

`empty(false)` is `true` but `empty(array(false))` is `false`-- the array is not empty. It has an element, even though that element is `false`. Play with `var_dump()` a bit and you can demonstrate it for yourself. Like this, for example:

```
$a = array(false);
var_dump($a);
var_dump(empty($a));
```

There is not enough context to your question/code for me to narrow it down further.

Comment: Thanks. Most of this I don't really understand. But I don't think I have anything you mentioned that would interfere like this. I only set up pre_get_posts but no filters. The parent theme uses filters involving get_post_meta but it's set to true. I created my custom post types via Pods. I just asked this in their forum. Maybe it's pods related.

Comment: "The parent theme uses filters involving get_post_meta but it's set to true." -- that sounds like you _do_ have something that could interfere like this.

Comment: I mean it uses it to determine whether to display sidebar or not. Just the regular code setup. I should maybe also say that this is the only instance where this happens. I'm using a ton of get_post_meta fields and none of them give me this problem. Usually like this: $win_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'win', true );

Comment: Checked again. Found this in parent theme's functions.php http://pastebin.com/dkEYagxG

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the connection. Is that code used in relation to the code in your question? If so, how?

Comment: No, but it's the only thing that I figured could maybe interfere with my code

Comment: If that code isn't being used in relation to your problem, and isn't hooked in anywhere relevant, it can't be the issue.

Comment: Ok, good I guess. Just to be sure, is any of the code you mentioned in your answer meant to be tested by me? Because I haven't, exept the vardump thing.

Comment: I can't write usable code-- code that you can use-- because I haven't identified the precise problem but those are the only places I see that it could go wrong.

Comment: Ok. I don't think I have any filters. How or where do I check the $object_id?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'll find out what caused this. Thank you so much for your help! In the meantime I realized I can use this:

```
<?php 
$work_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'work', false );
// check if the custom field has a value
    foreach ( $work_value as $work ) { 
        if(is_array($work)) {
        //get id for related post and put in ID
        $id = $work[ 'ID' ];
        //show the related post name as link
        echo 'for <a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a> ';
        }
    } //end of foreach

?>
```